# How to mock dispatch in vueJs testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I am currently performing unit tests on my application as seen. But I have a problem. How to mock or exploit the dispatch of Vuex ?

My method to test :

```
methodA({ dispatch, commit }, { data }) {
        dispatch('methodB', { data });
    }
  };
```

My unit test :

```
describe('UnitTesting', () => {
  it('if method called', () => {
    const commit = jest.fn();
    const dispatch = jest.fn('methodB');
    service.actions.methodA({ dispatch, commit });
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

I have a error message : Dispatch is not a function.
Why ? Do you help me please ? I don't understand why I had this message.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jest.fn('methodB')` is not not a proper call, thus the resulting `dispatch` constant not being a function.

The `fn` parameter should be a function.
Either do `jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('functionB'))` or `jest.fn().mockResolvedValue('functionB')`

But just `jest.fn()` would make it here.

Comment: Oh thank you it's working !! :) And last question : How I can to mock with jest the window.FB.api for facebook login ? thank you

Comment: Something like this `window.FB = { api: jest.fn() }; window.FB.api.mockImplementation( (path, method, params, callback) => callback({ whateverExpectedInResponse: true, }) )`

Comment: The same thing happens to me, how was your test after this?

Comment: Mi functions is,    

function addNewTodo() {
      let newTodo = { id: null, name: newTodoName.value, completed: false };
      store.dispatch("addTodo", newTodo);
      newTodoName.value = "";
    }

and this is the test: 
  it("dispatch method", () => {
    const dispatch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve('addTodo'))
    wrapper.vm.addNewTodo(dispatch)
    expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
What's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

In case you additionally want to create a localVue and have the store work normally in your tests you can use `spyOn`:

```js
const storeDispatch = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.$store, 'dispatch')
expect(storeDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith('module/action', {})
```